# Datetime Datatype not rendering on the view FLASK

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask

Everyone, I am writing this program related to transactions and in one view I am rendering the history of the transactions and for some reason the created_at column is not rendering the date when the transaction happened. Any tips?
here is the application.py:

```
def history():
    transactions = db.execute("SELECT symbol, shares, shares_price, created_at FROM bonds WHERE user_id = :user_id ORDER BY created_at ASC", user_id = session["user_id"])
    return render_template("history.html", transactions=transactions)
```

here is the view:

```
 {% for t in transactions %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ t.symbol }}</td>
                <td>{{ t.shares }}</td>
                <td>{{ (t.shares * t.shares_price) | usd }}</td>
                <td>{{ t.created_at }}</td>
            </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

and lastly here is the database file in case yall need it:

```
column: created_at  
datatype: DATETIME  
NULL: No    
default value: None 
primary key: No
```

Comment: sqlite does not have an internal [DATETIME data type](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). How is the row being inserted? Have you looked at the data in another tool, e.g. command line sqlite3?

Comment: I opened the sqlite3 terminal and ran ALTER TABLE bonds ADD COLUMN created_at DATETIME and I inserted it into the db. I dont really understand what u mean it doesnt have datetime. could you elaborate a bit more? @DinoCoderSaurus

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus how would you go and save the date and display?

Comment: The doc in the link describes it much better than I ever could. The data is "saved" in the database when rows are INSERTed into the bonds table.

Comment: I dont believe thats the problem. Python dbs do support datetime type, if it didnt I wouldnt be allowed to add the column into the table. The problem is in the update and showing it on the view @DinoCoderSaurus

Comment: Perhaps  edit some sample data in to the question that shows what data in `created_at` is not rendering in the HTML. The only explanation that is evident is that `created_at` is "empty". FWIW columns can be added to a sqlite database with any word (or words)  as the datatype. In sqlite3 "_the datatype is a property of the value itself, not of the column in which the value is stored._"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I added the date time field after the other fields were created so all of them were nil so I just dropped the table and added it again with the datetime field